# Display Opportunities from Sub Accounts on Parent

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to display all the opportunities linked to a Parent Account, including sub accounts, not just the ones directly linked to that Account. Only Opportunities relating to that Account appear at the moment. Is it possible to change it so that Opportunities linked to sub Accounts also appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get there i think you will need a report. Unfortunately build and advanced find query with your requirements it's not possible. Also with the report will be hard to get all the "sub opportunities" if the tree of accounts is bigger than 1 level:

```
Parent Account
Lv1 child account (parent: Parent Account)
Lv2 child account (parent: Lv1 child account)
```

If you have a structure like this get the Lv2 child account opportunities will not be possible if it's an online crm, and will be very complex if it's on premises.